Show that Proof by Contradiction rule is derivable from all instances of it with atomic conclusion
The problem shows up in Troelstra's Basic Proof Theory, exercise 2.3.6A.

Show that in [classical logic's Natural Deduction], for the languages without ∨, ∃, all instances of ⊥c derivable from instances ⊥c with atomic conclusions.

I have a solution to the problem, but I'm not sure if it's correct as it seems trivials, perhaps because I missed something.
In the natural deduction system given, there are intro & elim rules for each of the following connectives, as you would expect: ∧, →, and ∀ (ignoring ∨ and ∃, and note that there are no inference rules for ¬). Additionally, there is the proof by contradiction rule:

Since negation is defined in terms of implication and ⊥ (A ≡ A → ⊥), my thought was that we can break down D1 into two cases:

Given A → ⊥ for some non-atomic A, and ⊥ is obtained by →E on ¬A, then there is a proof of A. So we can replace the whole proof with just the proof of A.
If ⊥ is obtained independently from applying →E on ¬A, then we can utilize the proof of ⊥ by inserting it into relevant subproofs via a ∧I, then use ∧E to get rid of the original conclusion of the subproof and retain only ⊥. We break A down into further cases:

If A is B ∧ C, then we introduce two subproofs: one assumes ¬B and derives B by a use of ⊥c (we are guaranteed a proof of ⊥), and one assumes ¬C and derives C similarly. By ∧I we have a proof of B∧C.
If A is B → C, then we assume B, and assume ¬C to derive C by a use of ⊥c. By →I we have B → C
If A is ∀x B, then we assume ¬B and derive B by a use of ⊥c. Then by ∀I we have ∀x B.



In any cases above, we recursively reduce any subproofs we generate so that all instances of ⊥c involves atomic propositions.
Is this solution correct? Am I missing cases? It feels a bit too trivial.

Yes, your idea is correct. But there is one thing missing: Why the procedure that you described is terminating? Note that the answer is not so trivial because, for instance, in the case $A= B \land C$ you are replacing one instance of $\bot_c$ with two instances of $\bot_c$.

@Taroccoesbrocco I specified at the end that the procedure is recursively performed on any subproof it generates, which includes the two instances of ⊥c that is generated by handling B ∧ C. It also includes the proof of A in case 1. Does that handle the problem?

Morally, it is fine. But applying a procedure recursively actually means that you are proving a property by induction on some size on a well-founded set (for instance, the set of natural numbers). So, my question is: what is this this size? If you want to be really rigorous with your proof, you have to answer that question.

@Taroccoesbrocco It could be on the length of the derivation, but it’s not obvious that the subproofs I generate are of a shorter length than the original proof, so that might not be right.

@Taroccoesbrocco forgot to correct myself, it’s induction on the complexity of the formula used as an assumption in the proof by contradiction rule
